# WP_Query meta_query date range with 2 custom fields

Tags: wordpress, date-range

I have a custom post type 'events' that contains custom fields for start_date and end_date. I'm trying to make a simple list of upcoming events. If I query only events with a start_date >= today it works fine. If I add in a meta_query to say "AND" all events with an end_date <= today - it doesn't return anything.

My custom fields (start_date, end_date) are stored as unix timestamps, which is why I'm using 'NUMERIC' and 'meta_value_num'. $today is a timestamp of the current date. Here are examples of what I'm trying to do... Pulling my hair out - any help would be appreciated!

THIS WORKS:

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),

    )
);
```

When I add in a second array for the meta_query - DOES NOT WORK:

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),

    )
);
```

When I use meta_compare in the main query, and a single meta_query - DOES NOT WORK:

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'meta_value_num' => $today,
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'date',
        ),

    )
);
```

When I use meta_compare in the main query, and multiple meta_queries - DOES NOT WORK:

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'meta_value_num' => $today,
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),

    )
);
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how I'm using it and its working fine for me.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'job',
    'posts_per_page'   => 25,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'published_date',
            'value' => array('20140401','20140405'),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
));


if ($the_query->have_posts()) {

    echo '<ul>';
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

} else {
    echo 'Sorry! No Posts';
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

The most important note on the codex.

> The 'type' DATE works with the 'compare' value BETWEEN only if the date is **stored at the format YYYYMMDD** and tested with this format.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'meta_value_num' => $yesterday,
    'meta_compare' => '<=',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => array($first_minute,$last_minute),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'value' => $yesterday,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => $yesterday,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),


    )
)
```

This gets the current month's events. I input variables for first minute of month, last minute of month, and "yesterday" which is 11:59:59 of yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

Alexandru-Florentin Popescu is right! Use your code another following:

```
$args = array(  
'post_type' => 'events',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_key' => 'start_date',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'start_date',
        'value' => $today,
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'end_date',
        'value' => $today,
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
    ),

));
```

You just need change key 'compare' in both arrays

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what are you trying but seems logical to not return anything as you are selecting events that starts today or in the future (start_date >= $today) AND ends today or in the past (end_date <= $today)...